# Select 2 maximum values in SQL with concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking to answer this question:

*Write an SQL statement to display hotel name, room type, and the number of nights concatenated to the text "NIGHTS" and accessibility if the room is not accessible or room type is double. Display only the two largest numbers of nights. Change the alias of the calculated number of bookings to “NUM_OF_NIGHTS”.?*

This is the code which I have written so far:

```
SELECT HOTELNAME, ROOMTYPE, 
       CONCAT(NIGHTS,' NIGHTS ',ACCESSIBILITY) AS NUM_OF_NIGHTS
  FROM HOTEL, 
       ROOM, 
       BOOKING
 WHERE ACCESSIBILITY='N' 
    OR ROOMTYPE='DOUBLE';
```

I think I have to use the TOP function somewhere to display the 2 largest number of nights but I'm not sure where to integrate this into the code. I would appreciate it if someone could help me here.

Comment: You have a bigger problem to solve... that of learning proper way of using joins.

Comment: Do i have to use joins though as each attribute is unique to it's own table?

Comment: In its current form you query returns all combinations of hotel-room-bookings instead of matching room with hotel and booking with room.

Comment: Okay, so I would need to change it to something like this?:  SELECT H.HOTELNAME, R.ROOMTYPE, CONCAT(B.NIGHTS,' NIGHTS ',R.ACCESSIBILITY) AS NUM_OF_NIGHTS
FROM HOTEL H, ROOM R, BOOKING B
 WHERE H.HOTELID=R.HOTELID AND
    B.HOTELID=R.HOTELID AND
    ACCESSIBILITY='N' OR
   H.HOTELID=R.HOTELID AND
    B.HOTELID=R.HOTELID AND ROOMTYPE='DOUBLE';

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Thank you, I had tried using TOP before but didn't realise that it mattered what DBMS I'm using though. I'm using MySQL and as I've found out the TOP function can't be used in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT
     HOTELNAME
     , ROOMTYPE
     , CONCAT(NIGHTS,' NIGHTS ',ACCESSIBILITY) AS NUM_OF_NIGHTS
FROM HOTEL, 
     ROOM, 
     BOOKING
WHERE ACCESSIBILITY='N' 
     OR ROOMTYPE='DOUBLE'
ORDER BY NIGHTS DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this before but didn't realise that it mattered what DBMS I'm using though. I'm using MySQL and apparently the TOP function can't be used in it.

Comment: Thank you very much that has helped my tremendously